# HTTPS - Client data loss

Tags: https

I have noticed in Firefox using HTTPS if I type data into a form item such as a text box and press refresh the data is lost. If an error was thrown on a server after I pressed submit would this also cause the data to be lost?

If so, Is there a way to stop this from happening (from the server side)?

Thanks for viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a browser implementation feature. In FireFox there is a configuration option you can set to cache pages received through HTTPS but you will need an external tool to store the data you type into a form received through https as most browsers don't store this information for security reasons.